# How to animate multiple lines consecutively

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

### Problem description

I want to create an animation in Python. The data I have looks e.g. like this:

```
    vals        time        cat
0   -0.099010   0.000000    A
1   0.168527    0.128228    A
2   0.293790    0.256457    A
3   0.158375    0.384685    A
4   0.245166    0.512913    A
.
.
145 -0.545781   5.770272    C
146 -0.415403   5.898500    C
147 -0.319901   6.026729    C
148 -0.122130   6.154957    C
149 -0.013237   6.283185    C
```

I would like to produce a final animated plot, which looks similar to the plot below:

[image: example plot]

The animation should be animated **consecutively**, that is first series A, then B and finally C.

---

**Problem:** When creating the animation, the last point of one category is linked to the first point of the next category.

**Question:** How do I avoid the connecting lines between the last and the first point of different categories?

**Extra bonus question:** How do I add different colors for each category?

[image: example-animation]

---

### MWE

**Data**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
data = [np.sin(t) + 0.1*np.random.randn(50) for i in range(3)]
data = np.hstack(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['vals'])
data['time'] = np.hstack([t] * 3)
data['cat'] = 'A'
data.loc[50:100, 'cat'] = 'B'
data.loc[100:, 'cat'] = 'C'
```

**Animation**

```py
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
def animate(i):
    temp = data.iloc[:1 + int(i)] #select temp range
    p = ax.plot(temp['time'], temp['vals'], color='r')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=150, repeat=False)
ani.save('myanim.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Comment: every line should be draw with separated `plot()`

Answer (score 1):

- One way is to separate the data by `'cat'`. Currently, the animation plots all of the data as a single group, without consideration for the different `'cat'` values.
- The legend needs to be manually created because using `label=cat` adds a new legend handle for every `i` in the animation

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D  # for legend

def animate(i):
    
    # create a color dict for each cat
    cd = dict(zip(data.cat.unique(), ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange', 'tab:green']))
    
    # select each cat group and plot with a different color
    for cat in data.cat.unique():
        data_cat = data[data.cat.eq(cat)]
    
        temp = data_cat.iloc[:1 + int(i)] #select temp range
        p = ax.plot(temp['time'], temp['vals'], color=cd[cat])

    # create custom legend lines
    custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color=v, lw=2, label=k) for k, v in cd.items()]
    
    ax.legend(title='cat', handles=custom_lines)


Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']

# increase the frame rate
writer = Writer(fps=30, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

# frames is the length of the data / 3 because there are 3 cat groups
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=int(len(data)/3), repeat=False)
    
ani.save('myanim.mp4', writer=writer)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I want to plot the different categories consecutively, so unfortunately, plotting all categories simultaneoulsy like in your answer is  not an option.